# get absolute URL with EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

How can I build up an absolute URL using no scriptlets (only EL) to the current server, using the current protocol, port, application etc?

Comment: Absolute URL to where? From what information? We need a lot more information to help you, I'm afaid..

Comment: like this: `String s = "http://www.example.com"` :) Well, jokes apart, what do you mean exactly? Building from what? And, pardon my ignorance, what is "EL"?

Comment: Sorry All, I mean to the current server. Using the current protocol and port etc

Comment: @MarcoS: hover the `[el]` tag below the question and read the popbox and click if necessary the `info` link therein.

Comment: @BalusC: ah, stupid me! thank you for suggesting this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the base URL up to with the context root with help of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) as follows:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, pageContext.request.contextPath)}" />
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${baseURL}/foo.css" />
<script src="${baseURL}/foo.js"></script>
<a href="${baseURL}/foo.jsp">link</a>
```

Comment: In my setup, this results in a URL with `http` instead of `https`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is:

```
http://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/thePage.jsp
```

Comment: `localPort` is however incorrect. Use `serverPort`. The only disadvantage of this way is that you still ends with an ugly port number in URL when the site runs on default HTTP ports 80 or 443.

Comment: Thanks. Of course. Well spotted. For my use the ports are not default, otherwise i'd simply leave it off.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another way is:

```
  <c:set var="serverPath" value="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

I'm quite surprised when the GitHub Copilot just suggested the code snippet. ~~ :)