# Get an absolute URL in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In a JSP page, I need to have an absolute URL of on of my page in order to do some integration with twitter.

This is what I have

```
<spring:url value="/blog/article1" var="articleUrl" />
<spring:url value="https://twitter.com/share" var="twitter" >
  <spring:param name="url" value="${articleUrl}"/>
</spring:url>
<a href="${twitter}">Tweet</a>
```

My problem is that it generates :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=/myWebSite/blog/article1">Tweet</a>
```

And of course, twitter do not like relative URL...
Is there a simple way to have the absolute URL (with spring:url or c:url or other...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my response on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704712/get-absolute-url-with-el) :

```
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, pageContext.request.contextPath)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore more about **context** attribute in `<spring:url/>` tag. I think it would be helpful to you.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: The context attribute is used to set the context path.

Comment: Then you can specify the context path youself there and it will give you the whole url.

Comment: If your suggestion is to put the absolute url of the application as the context, since my problem was to know this absolute URL, it does not help me. My application run on several different server so I can not hardcode the url.