# When to use spring:url tag?

Tags: spring, url, tags

I think the question is the same for [huge manipulations with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704712/get-absolute-url-with-el) (ie Why?). Where people just reconstruct the URL from scratch.

Does it not hinder the visibility of the app for UI developers if all they see:

```
<link href="${some_url_possibly_not_named_logically_i_e_karamba1243}/less/bootstrap.less"/>
```

I just don't understand use cases where these tags are used and why should I?
How can this example snippet be improved with usage of spring:url tag? Would it be used just to remove repetitive part of URL?

```
<div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/futfarm/home/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/futfarm/person/myProfile/">My Profile</a></li>


                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_Coach')">

                    <li><a href="/futfarm/coach/training/viewbank">Training</a></li>
                </sec:authorize>

                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_Player')">

                    <li><a href="/futfarm/player/training/viewbank">Training</a></li>
                </sec:authorize>


                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_Manager')">

                    <li><a href="/futfarm/manager/administration">Administration</a></li>
                </sec:authorize>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Or the major concern is that if same URL will be used in another .jsp we can just grab a variable, but then again this tag is specific to jsp scope so other pages cannot use it. I
What's wrong with the traditional approach? Are there examples where I can't use anything but spring:url.

It is exactly one of those cases where everyone uses it, no one explains(even google - providing super url reconstruction cases) and everyone happy except me, feeling confused and dumb :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it when you need to have dynamic components in generated URLs (e.g. `/app/resources/{name}`) and when you need to make sure those URL components (e.g. `{name}` as above) are properly escaped. Look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) for more info.

Also note that you CAN have global attributes that you use with e.g. the `<spring:url />` tag across multiple JSPs. Have a look at `setExposedContextBeanNames(String[])` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html).